# Iterate network analyst closest facility, arcpy error

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, loop, iteration

I am working on simulating resource deployments within arcpy network analyst.
I have individual incidents stored in a file database (they have to remain single because later on the script must do a check to ensure there is a resource to deploy. My problem is with the iteration. The first closest facility analysis works but then the script fails before completing the next one.
It returns

```
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: A python error occurred.
Failed to execute (FindClosestFacilities).
```

This is my code snippet below

```
import arcpy
import time
arcpy.env.workspace = r"c:\Simulation\incidents.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
start = time.clock()
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Network")
featureclasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

print featureclasses

for fc in featureclasses:       
    arcpy.env.workspace = r"c:\Simulation\incidents.gdb"
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    inNetworkDataset = r"c:\Simulation\tempFGDB.gdb\deccan_street\deccan_street_ND"
    inIncidents = fc
    inFacilities = r"c:|Simulation\proposed_csl.shp"
    outGeodatabase = r"c:\Simulation\NA_outputs.gdb"
    outRoutes = "Routes"
    outDirections ="Directions"
    outClosestFacilities = "ClosestFacilities"
    measurement_units = "Minutes"
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,("DATE_TIME", "OBJECTID")) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            vALUE = str(row[1])

    # Run FindClosestFacilities. Choose to find only the closest facility.
    arcpy.na.FindClosestFacilities(fc, inFacilities, measurement_units, inNetworkDataset, outGeodatabase, outRoutes + "_" + vALUE, outDirections + "_" + vALUE, outClosestFacilities + "_" + vALUE, Number_of_Facilities_to_Find=1)

print "Script completed successfully"

elapsed = (time.clock() - start)
print("Execution time: " + str(elapsed))
```

Comment: What purpose does the search cursor solve? `VALUE` never changes since you are always getting the last OID each iteration of the outer for loop.

Comment: To identify outputs, I don't know how to call specific field values from the feature class list directly and pass it to append to output names

Comment: When you define InFacilities it is using the wrong slash in path.

Comment: Yep, InFacilites.  Also, consider using an error handler in your scripts.  If the script fails the error handler will return more detailed information about why it failed- both from the arcpy side of things and the Python/syntax side .   http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/python/error-handling-with-python.htm

Comment: The InFacilities slash changed somehow when I copied and pasted my code. However even with that fixed and the error handler I get the same generic errors.

Comment: What is the precise and full error message that you receive when you run the precise error that you have presented?